# How to preserve Mosby's Presenter when using Conductor framework in Android?

Tags: android, mvp, mosby

Probably the answer is "you can't", because in Mosby 2.0 you need to use fragment and set it to setRetainInstance(true) to preserve Presenter. And the aim of Conductor is to remove the need of using Fragments, so there is no way to use setRetainInstance(true) anywhere in your app.

But maybe there IS another way..

Comment: I really like conductor. This will be coming very very soon. Will not be part of Mosby 3.0 library, but I will provide another library that provides a binding from Mosby to Conductor to integrate it easily. I plan to work on this and Mosby 3.0 at the end of April. Probably a snapshot is available next week.

Comment: Cool, share your solution here when you got it and I will mark it as an answer. :) Thank you very much for your amazing work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the official Mosby plugin for Conductor:

https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby-conductor

Comment: What is the lifecycle of presenter? Does it survive configuration change?

Comment: Pretty similar to fragment / activites. Presenter lives as long as View lives. so basically presenter is created in Conductors controllers `onCreateView()` and destoyed in controllers `onDestroyView()`, except screen orientation changes. So yes, presenter survive screen orientation changes.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry i cannot comment because i don't have enough reputation but Conductor is using Conductor.attachRouter in order to take instance inside an activity and attachRouter is using the LifecycleHandler in order to take a "saved" (aka retained instance) because LifecycleHandler is a headless fragment. So in order for you to have a presenter which is not being destroyed on configuration changes all you have to do it to create your presenter inside the constructor of the controller. If i have understand right, the constructor of the controller has the life time of a headless fragment. So problem solved or i might have made a mistake somewhere...

Comment: You are correct. This cleared up a lot of things for me, thanks.